# Can you evolve a Basic pokemon to its stage 2 with the TM Evolution?

Tags: pokemon

So pretty much how the title says but can you use the Item tool card Technical Machine: Evolution to evolve a Basic bench Pokémon to its stage 2?

Technical Machine: Evolution

**Choose up to 2 of your Benched Pokémon. For each of those Pokémon, search your deck for a card that evolves from that Pokémon and put it onto that Pokémon to evolve it. Then, shuffle your deck.**

Why I am asking is because a friendship told you could. So just wanted a professional awnser.

Comment: It seems obvious the answer is "yes", it's what it says on the card. Why might the answer be 'no'?

Comment: @Allure Basic -> stage 2 is two evolutions. I think they are asking if you can pick the stage 1 evolved pokemon that they searched for as the second pokemon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Unless a card says otherwise, you follow the usual evolution rules. *A card that evolves from X* is a card that has *Evolves from X* printed on it.

From [Pokémon TCG Rulebook](https://www.pokemon.com/static-assets/content-assets/cms2/pdf/trading-card-game/rulebook/par_rulebook_en.pdf), chapter *Turn Actions*, part *Evolve Pokémon*:

> *If you have a card in your hand that says "Evolves from X," and X is the name of a Pokémon you had in play at the beginning of your turn, you may play that card in your hand on top of Pokémon X. This is called "evolving" a Pokémon.*
>
> *You may evolve a Basic Pokémon to a Stage 1 Pokémon or a Stage 1 Pokémon to a Stage 2 Pokémon. (…)*